# eCommerce website- Updating Cart Items in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

> **UnboundLocalError at /cart/** - error message from website carts/views.py", 
>   **line 24, in update_cart   if not product in cart.products.all(): UnboundLocalError: local variable 'product' referenced before
>   assignment

This is the error message I receive when I click the 'add to cart' button on my website.** - error message in terminal

***views.py*** - here is my views for the cart. From my understanding the issue seems to be in this file.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your views here
```

.

```
from fuisce.models import Product

from .models import Cart

def view(request):
    cart = Cart.objects.all()[0]
    context = {"cart": cart}
    template = "cart/view.html"
    return render(request, template, context)

def update_cart(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart.objects.all()[0]
    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(product_id=product_id)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    except:
        pass
    if not product in cart.products.all():
        cart.products.add(product)
    else:
        cart.products.remove(product)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cart'))

***urls.py***

from django.urls import path
from . import views
from carts import views as cart_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('cart/', cart_views.view, name='cart'),
    path('cart/<product_id>', cart_views.update_cart, name='update_cart'),
]


***models.py - cart ***

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from fuisce.models import Product

class Cart(models.Model):
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)    
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __string__(self):
        return "Cart id: %s" %(self.id)

***models.py -Product***
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    desc = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)    
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='fuisce/images', default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

I believe these files contain the problem but from researching online I can't seem to pinpoint exactly what it is. The cart on my website was working until i modiefied my views.py file. 
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue is you are declaring the `product` variable inside try-except block, and not handling error properly

```
def update_cart(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart.objects.all()[0]

    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(product_id=product_id)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        product=None
        print('Exception Occured')
    except:
        product=None
        print('Exception Occured')

    if not product in cart.products.all():
        cart.products.add(product)
    else:
        cart.products.remove(product)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cart'))
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I have tried the suggested code above and I am now receiving a different error message. I am not sure where this is coming from as all was working perfectly earlier.                                                                  
This is the error message I am getting now --> IntegrityError at /cart/<django.db.models.fields.AutoField>
NOT NULL constraint failed: carts_cart_products.product_id

Comment: Could you check in ```if not product in cart.products.all():
        cart.products.add(product)
    else:
        cart.products.remove(product)```,  what condition is true?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by this? I'm new to python and django so it can be confusing to understand